# Detect before user closes/changes mobile browser tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone

Is it possible to detect before the user changes tab or closes the tab on a mobile browser.

I tried

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
           // AddToCart(123, 123, 123, 123);
            return "Message";
        });
```

but that did not work.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `onbeforeunload` instead,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

NOTE: Modern browsers display their own message rather than custom message for security reasons

Comment: That does not work on mobile browser, at least on Chrome 0.39.x (Android 4.4) nor safari mobile on iOS 8.0.2.